# no such column name error

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I defined column name. but I confront this error. I checked every thing. I cant find the reason of this error .

```
 try {
         myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

         /* Create a Table in the Database. */
         myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
           + TableName
           + " (" +
           "name TEXT, " +
           "number TEXT" +
               ");"
           );

         /* Insert data to a Table*/
         myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
           + TableName
           + "(name,number)"
           + " VALUES (name,number)");

        // retrieve data from database
         Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);


         // Check if our result was valid.
         c.moveToFirst();


             while(c.moveToNext())
                {
                 Log.i("error",c.getString(0));
                 Log.i("error",c.getString(1) ); 
             contactname.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
             contactnumber.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")));

              }
```

Comment: You forgot that your columns are TEXT (**'** string delimiters are needed!). Try `+ " VALUES ('name', 'number')");` in your INSERT command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
/* Insert data to a Table*/
 myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
   + TableName
   + "(name,number)"
   + " VALUES (name,number)");
```

tries to insert name, number which are both identified as column names since they are no strings. You should insert it like:

```
/* Insert data to a Table*/
 myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
   + TableName
   + "(name, number)"
   + " VALUES (\"name\",\"number\")");
```

Comment: thanks. but number and value in VALUES are variable not value.

Comment: In that case you need to put them out of the string, and do not forget to escape them properly.